# Set Sails Log Level to Silent when using Mocha

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

How do you set the Sails.js log level to `silent` only when running Mocha tests? I need the Sails app to stay at `silly` when running outside of the mocha tests.

This is found in the `sails.config.log` file:

```
module.exports.log = {
  level: 'silly'
};
```

This is my Mocha bootstrap.test.js file:

```
var sails = require('sails');

before(function(done) {
  this.timeout(5000);
  sails.lift({

  }, function(err) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  sails.lower(done);
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding an argument when lifting the sails app in the `bootstrap.test.js` file.

```
sails.lift({
    log: { 
        level: 'silent'
    }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(err, sails);
});
```